# SQL How to construct a query that two columns from one table depending on another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Please take a look at my table structure as below:

[image]

The data in **Area_PrimaryTable** and **Area_SecondaryTable** will be mapped to `Table_TableID`. I'm wondering how to get the status ID for both table 100 and 111 when I'm querying `AreaID` = A101?

```
Select * from Area where AreaID = A101
```

**UPDATES:**
I've found my way to build such query but not sure if there is any better way?

Please advise as below:

```
Select * from Table where TableID in
(
    Select PrimaryTable from Area where AreaID = 'A101'
    union
    Select SecondaryTable from Area where AreaID = 'A101'      
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the kind of example where `JOIN`s are especially useful. Look that up, since `JOIN`s are something that ends up being used very, very often when working with SQL. They basically allow you to get information from several related tables as part of the same record.

So there you want to get information from two rows of Table, their relationship being that they are linked to the same row in Area. And I will consider you just want to get both status. That can be solved with the following code :

```
SELECT t1.Status, t2.Status
FROM   Area AS a
  JOIN Table AS t1 ON t1.TableID = a.PrimaryTable
  JOIN Table AS t2 ON t2.TableId = a.SecondaryTable
WHERE AreaID = 'A101'
```

Note that while using `SELECT *` is OK in my book when one experiments, I believe it should be avoided in production code in favour of explicitely naming the columns you want to get information from.

*Edit: despite the apparent differences, note that my code proposal has the same behaviour as Xtoxico's. Both proposals are equivalent as far as I know.*

Comment: Have to disagree on one little point, Xtoxico's proposal is not exactly equivalent, yes it yields the same result, but under the hood he is doing a `CROSS JOIN` (`FROM Area as a, table as t1, table as t2`) which at first gets a much larger result set than needed and then reduces that result with a `WHERE`, in your case you are doing an `INNER JOIN` which reduces the result set earlier thus pulling less data from the database ;)

Comment: I've run an `EXPLAIN` on a similar construct in one of the databases I am working with, on both queries, and MySQL works the same in both cases. I guess in the present case it optimizes the query, recognizing the pattern. However you are right in that it is much better to get used to `JOIN`ing properly since in cases less trivial that this one there might be an important difference indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this....

```
SELECT
    t1.status as StatusPrimary, t2.status as StatusSecondary 
FROM
    Area as a, 
    table as t1, 
    table as t2 
WHERE 
    a.primaryTable=t1.TableID and 
    a.secondaryTable=t2.TableId and 
    a.AreaID = A101;
```

Your Sample return two rows, and my code return in the same row the information

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this one:

```
select t.* from table t, area a
where a.AreaID = 'A101' 
and t.TableID in (a.PrimaryTable, a.SecondaryTable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
SELECT a.AreaID, t.TableID, t.TableName, t.Status FROM table1 t
INNER JOIN (
    Select PrimaryTable, areaId from Area
    union
    Select SecondaryTable, areaID from Area
) a ON t.TableID = a.PrimaryTable order by a.AreaID
```

Output will look like this (base on your table's structure)

[image]

I hope this is the answer what you looking for, if you only need find Area A101 , you can simply add `WHERE AreaID = 'A101'` after `a ON t.TableID = a.PrimaryTable`.

EDIT : Sorry missed the point, maybe the query should like this :

```
SELECT a.AreaID,
   MAX(IF(a.PrimaryTable = t.TableID, t.Status, null)) as T1,
   MAX(IF(a.SecondaryTable = t.TableID, t.status,null)) as T2
FROM Table1 t INNER JOIN Area a ON a.PrimaryTable = t.TableID OR a.SecondaryTable = t.TableID
GROUP BY AreaID
```